# "Blob does not exist" After a successful run of Logic App with SFTP In-App Connector

Tags: azure-blob-storage, sftp, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

So I've got a Logic App that takes a newly uploaded file from sharepoint and SFTP's it over to an SFTP enabled blob container. It runs successfully, however, when I go to click on the blob that is uploaded to the container I see this:

[image]

I feel like the odd " \ " at the beginning of the blob name may have something to do with it, but not 100% sure.

Here is my Logic App setup:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there something different I should be doing here? Personally, I thought it was a little weird that I'm only passing the file name to the "Upload file content" SFTP connector.

For more context, I do need to use the "In-App" version of the SFTP connector inside of the Logic App so that I can route the traffic through one IP.

Comment: I feel this is a bug with In app connector

Answer (score 1):

Even I have faced same issue as you have due to which I have raised a [Git hub bug request](https://github.com/Azure/logicapps/issues/1000):

**`Design:`**

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

As an alternative i can suggest you to not use in app for this connector and follow below design:

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]